# Problemas con awaitMessages de Discord.js V14

Tags: discord.js, bot

estoy intentando hacer que el Bot me reciba una imagen del autor que ejecutó el comando estoy haciendo todo lo necesario para eso, pero al momento de esperar la imagen si un usuario diferente la envía esta es recibida, pero no es solo la imagen recibe también cualquier cosa que se envíe

**Código**

```js
await m.channel.send('Envía el nombre del personaje');

const filter = msg => msg.author.id === m.author.id && msg.content !== ' ';
const response = await m.channel.awaitMessages({filter,  max: 1, time: 280000 });
if(!response.size) {
    return;
}
const name = response.first().content.toLowerCase();
                    
await m.channel.send('Envía una imagen o la URL de una imagen');
            
const imageFilter = msg => msg.author.id === m.author.id && msg.attachments.first() ||  msg.content.startsWith('http');
const imageResponse = await m.channel.awaitMessages({imageFilter,  max: 1, time: 280000 });
if (!imageResponse.size) {
    return;
}
const url = imageResponse.first().attachments.first() ? imageResponse.first().attachments.first().url : imageResponse.first().content;
```

el primer filtro funciona perfectamente el segundo hace su función de recibir la imagen pero la recibe de cualquier usuario

saben como puedo resolverlo??